# HTML5 mp3 + ogg playback with dynamic playlist

Tags: html, audio, playlist

I cannot figure out how to incorporate ogg files into a playlist for an HTML5  tag. Right now I read files from a directory JSON object that formats as follows:

```
 var playlist = [{"url":"mp3\/122911.mp3","title":"122911"},    
 {"url":"mp3\/100909.mp3","title":"100909"},{"url":"mp3\/011110.mp3","title":"011110"},
 {"url":"mp3\/061207C.mp3","title":"061207C"},{"url":"mp3\/110309.mp3","title":"110309"},    
 {"url":"mp3\/120409.mp3","title":"120409"},{"url":"mp3\/031608.mp3","title":"031608"},     
 {"url":"mp3\/100609C.mp3","title":"100609C"},{"url":"mp3\/120408.mp3","title":"120408"},
  {"url":"mp3\/012908.mp3","title":"012908"},{"url":"mp3\/032107.mp3","title":"032107"}]
```

that works wonders and loading the ogg files into that object is not the issue. I just need to know how to tell firefox that the ogg files are there.  Is there a parameter I'm missing in order to do that along with 'url' and 'title' in the JSON? I know it can go right in the audio tag if I'm just creating everything statically, but I'm not. The audio tag is simply:

```
 <audio class="aud" autoplay>
    <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML 5 audio.</p>
</audio>
```

and it works just fine with the mp3s in chrome and safari so far. I know I'm missing something simple. I have the ogg files, just confused about the parameters in the playlist I suppose. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How this is working?

```
<audio class="aud" autoplay>
    <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML 5 audio.</p>
</audio>
```

There is no source. Are you dynamically adding `<source>` to the `<audio>`?

Let me tell how it works:

You can specify multiple `<source` for the `<audio>`. Browsers will look top to bottom in the `<source>`s and try to play the first one it supports. So, if you write this way:

```
<audio class="aud" autoplay>
    <source src="music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">   
    <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML 5 audio.</p>
</audio>
```

This will be sufficient. Browses, that support mp3, will use the first source. If the browser, like firefox, that does not support mp3 will discard this and look next. It will find .ogg next and will play that one.

You can see more here:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp